# ASP.Net Core Anchor route to action in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, anchor

I am trying to make an anchor execute a controller method, which is not working for me. This is my anchor:

```
<div class="topNavigationBar">
    <a href="default/GoToGames">Games</a>
</div>
```

My controller is called `Default` and its ActionResult method which I want to execute is called `GoToGames`:

```
public IActionResult GoToGames()
{
    return View("/Views/Games.cshtml");
}
```

I tried this:

```
<a asp-controller="Default" asp-action="GoToGames">Apps</a>
```

Which just makes the anchor unclickable. How can I make the anchor route to the ActionResult?

Comment: "Which just makes the anchor unclickable." => can you share the HTML generated?

Comment: I am sorry but where can I find this generated HTML? Do you mean the "view source"?

Comment: Load the page, right click on the element and select Inspect Element (assuming Chrome/Firefox), there you'll see the HTML rendered by ASP.NET Core

Comment: It gives back the same code: <a href="default/GoToGames">Games</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Views folder, create the file `_ViewImports.cshtml` and add the below line:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: @mth1417 It worked because you aren't using TagHelpers with that code, and the HtmlHelpers might be removed in the future so you better don't stick to them. If this updated answer is right, that is